# Cloud9 - MySQL DATETIME format

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am having an issue using the MySQL DATETIME format in Cloud 9.

MySQL reference states that the DATETIME format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, this is what I have done, but it keeps giving me a syntax error regarding the DATETIME format.

The error I'm getting is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. '2018-05-01 12:12:12')' at line 2
```

My JavaScript code (partial):

```
result = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
                var login = document.getElementById('login');
                login.value=result;
```

MySQL code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Customer(customer_id, first_name, last_name, email, phone_home, phone_mobile, user_type_id, password, pasword_hashed, login)
VALUES ('', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$phone_home', '$phone_mobile', '$user_type_id', '$password', '$password_hashed'. '$login')";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a "." lost inside your query:

```
'$password_hashed'. '$login'
```

You probably want a comma (,).

```
'$password_hashed', '$login'
```

Comment: Yeah, it took me a while (too long) to spot that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. It was literally a full stop at "`$password_hashed'. '$login'`". Eurgh!